# How to use Eventlog and query?

Tags: powershell-3.0, event-log

I'm trying to use `ExportLog()` for getting specified date eventlog. The following code works fine:

```bsh
$Filter = "*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='2016-01-29T15:00:00.000Z' and @SystemTime<='22016-01-30T14:59:59.999Z']]]"
for ( $i = 0 ;$i -lt  $LogName.count; $i++ ) {
    $OutFileName = $LogName[$i] + "_" + $LogDate + ".evtx"
    $OutFolders  = $OutFolder + "\" + $LogName[$i]
    $OutFile     = $OutFolders + "\" + $OutFileName

    Write-Output $OutFile

    if ((Test-Path $OutFolders) -eq $false){
        New-Item -Path $OutFolders -Type directory
    }
    if ((Test-Path $OutFile) -eq $true){
        Remove-Item $OutFile
    }

    $evsession = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession
    $evsession.ExportLog($LogName[$i], "LogName", $Filter, $OutFile)
```

but this did not work as I expected:

```bsh
$LogDate   = (Get-Date).AddDays($fromDay).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$StartTime =
  [DateTime] (Get-Date).AddDays($fromDay).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00")

$EndUtcTime1   
  [DateTime] (Get-Date).AddDays($fromDay).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd 23:59:59")

$Filter = "*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>= '$StartTime' and @SystemTime<= '$EndUtcTime' ]]]"

# after this it's the same as the above code snippet
```

Does anynone know the reason why it does not work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your second code sample doesn't work because it's formatting the timestamp incorrectly. Timestamps in the eventlog use a format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK` whereas you're using a format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`.

Change your date calculations to this:

```bsh
$fmtTimestamp = 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK'
$fmtDate      = 'yyyyMMdd'

$date = (Get-Date).AddDays($fromDay).ToUniversalTime().Date

$LogDate     = $date.ToString($fmtDate)
$StartTime   = $date.ToString($fmtTimestamp)
$EndUtcTime1 = $date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1).ToString($fmtTimestamp)
```